# Append dimensional numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

I have two numpy array matrix A and B of length 32 and shape (32, 32, 3) each . I want to combine them into a new array so that the dimensions of my new array is (2, 32, 32,3).

Using np. concatenate is throwing an error.

Comment: What error does `concatenate` throw?  We want details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `np.stack`

```
def dim0_stack(*arrays):
    return np.stack(arrays, axis = 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it:

```
a = np.random.randn(32, 32, 3)
b = np.random.randn(32, 32, 3)
c = np.concatenate([np.expand_dims(a,0), np.expand_dims(b, 0)], axis=0)
print(c.shape)
```

Because you mentioned using `concatenate`, I thought to show you how you can use it.

Answer (score 1):

Another more literal method

```
result = np.zeros((2, A.shape[0], A.shape[1], A.shape[2]))
result[0, :, :, :] = A
result[1, :, :, :] = B
```